# Add an App not functioning

Tags: simperium

When I go to the add an app button, enter my Gmail address, nothing happens and I receive no email with an app key. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

After you've created your Simperium account and logged in you should see the 'Add App' button over on the left bar.  Clicking it will ask you for an app name.  Your API key will show on your app summary page.  I don't remember getting emails on app creation.

If you've already created your app and want the API key for it, you can select it over on the left bar.